# Flask MongoEngine Paginated Documents with Image Field

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

Not seeing this exact question posted, so feel free to point to it if it exists.  I'm also new to mongo, so my verbiage is likely weird.

I have a document collection which will eventually grow very large.  I have set up so that the document has an ImageField.  I want to return the full document along with the ImageField's thumbnail populated as a file such that I can display it in my html5/javascript front end.

In SQL this would be accomplished through a column selector and a join.

See here:

```
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
import datetime

db = MongoEngine()

class img_audit(db.Document):
    request_image = db.ImageField(size=(1920, 1080, True), thumbnail_size=(100, 100, True))
    processed_date = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    state = db.StringField()
    city = db.StringField()
```

Query:

```
form = request.form
dpage = form['page']
perpage = form['perpage']
pag_audits = img_audit.objects.paginate(page=int(dpage), per_page=int(perpage))
pag_res = []
for item in pag_audits.items:
    pag_res.append(item.to_json())
return jsonify({'audits' : pag_res})
```

Currently the query simply returns the _oid of the ImageField as if it were a nested document.  How can I get just the thumbnail and return all of this in one whirl?

On the user interface, when the user clicks on the thumbnail, I will do a get request for the high definition image.

THANKS for any tips!

-------UPDATE 1--------------

Tried the following:

```
pag_audits = img_audit.objects.only('processed_date', 'state', 'city', 'request_image.thumbnail').paginate(page=int(dpage), per_page=int(perpage))
```

Getting the following error:
mongoengine.errors.LookUpError: Cannot resolve subfield or operator thumbnail on the field request_image

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using Mongo as a key/value and Azure Blob storage to store the files.  This ended up being a better solution for a variety of reasons from cost to content delivery and scale-ability.